# How can one show that this integral is Riemann integrable?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

It is given that $$ f:[a,b] \mapsto C~ \text{is Riemann integrable with b>a}$$ and i have to show that $$ \overline{f}:[a,b] \mapsto C~ \text{is Riemann integrable} $$ and $$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \overline{f(x)} \,dx=\overline{\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx }$$

Comment: Hint: Using the Riemann sum.

Comment: yes i tried that but i'm confused over this f complement thing @ntt

Comment: You can write your argument and we will check it step by step.

Comment: sorry but i'm having problem doing that @ntt

Comment: Don't worry, write what you have done so far.

Comment: i was thinking like this , if f is riemann integrable then $$ \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx+ \displaystyle \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$$

Comment: It is pretty inconsiderate to deface your question after it has been answered.

Comment: sorry it wasn't intentional , i was using mobile phone and it got erased by mistake i'm really sorry , and can i somehow reverse the edit ? @pjs36

Comment: thank you for reediting it @pjs36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Riemann sum,
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\xi_k)(x_{k}-x_{k-1})\;\;\mbox{(the limit is taken in } \mathbb C),$$
where $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b$ and $\xi_k \in [x_k, x_{k-1}]$ with $\max_{1\leqslant k \leqslant n}|x_{k}-x_{k-1}|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Now, by the properties of conjunction
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{f(\xi_k)}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})=\overline{\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\xi_k)(x_{k}-x_{k-1})}=\overline{\int_a^b f(x)dx}.$$
These equalities imply that $\overline{f}$ is also Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b \overline{f(x)}dx = \overline{\int_a^b f(x)dx}$.

Comment: sorry for asking but how did you write the first step ?

Comment: The first step is the definition of Riemann sum. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: and what is the meaning of the overline here ? @nttt

Comment: Overline is the conjunction of a complex number, i.e. $\overline{a+i b} = a-ib$, $a, b \in \mathbb R$.